# image resize and then rotate in canvas - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, rotation

I am using an image with size 1024 x 768 and I have a canvas size 300 x 300 so I want to resize my image first to 300 x 300 and then rotate it within the canvas proportionally. 
I am using following code but it is resizing the image but rotating some elements outside the canvas. So if you click right then you dont see anything and then hit right again then you will the image with down rotated.

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var degrees=0;
var image=document.createElement("img");
image.onload=function(){
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,300,300);
}
image.src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Outdoors/Landscapes/landscapes-275a.jpg";
image.width = 300;
image.height = 300;
 $("#clockwise").click(function(){
     degrees+=90
     ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
     ctx.save();
     ctx.translate(300,300);
     ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
     ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,300,300);
     ctx.restore();
});
```

Please check my code in JSFiddle as well
http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/914/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this variation.

- Translate to the center of the canvas.
- DrawImage with an [x,y] offset of image.width/2 & image.height/2. This offset is required because translate effectively makes the canvas centerpoint[150,150] to be the new canvas origin[0,0].  You need the negative offset to pull the drawing leftward and upward to compensate for the new origin.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var degrees=0;

var image=document.createElement("img");
image.onload=function(){
  ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,300,300);
}
image.src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Outdoors/Landscapes/landscapes-275a.jpg";


$("#clockwise").click(function(){
  degrees+=90
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(150,150);
  ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
  ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width,image.height,-150,-150,300,300);
  ctx.restore();
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
<button id="clockwise">Rotate right</button>
```